# Cant call an Arraylist from main() to another method outside main()

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I made an ArrayList inside `public static void main(String[] args)`

With the following code:

```
ArrayList<kistenEigenschaften> kisten = new ArrayList<kistenEigenschaften>(75);
```

kistenEigenschaften is properly defined in its own class.

But now I want to call that ArrayList in the folowwing method:

```
public static void kistenListe() {

        System.out.println("Sie haben " + kisten.size() + " kisten am lager.");
        for (int i = 0; i < kisten.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Kiste NR: " + kisten.get(i).getidNr() + ". Größe ist " + kisten.get(i).getBreite() + " cm breit " + kisten.get(i).getLänge() + " cm lang " + kisten.get(i).getHöhe() + " cm Höhe.");
        }
    }
```

Outside of main()

But cant seem to be able to call that arraylist outside main()

Tried the search function and could not find any solution, sorry if it was already mentioned.

Comment: Define your `ArrayList` outside the main method.

Comment: Add the ArrayList as a Parameter of `kistenListe` or define the List as property of the class not as local variable in the main function

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible Solutions:

First: Add the list as patameter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ArrayList<kistenEigenschaften> kisten = new ArrayList<kistenEigenschaften>(75);
   ....
   kistenListe(kisten);
}

public static void kistenListe(List<kistenEigenschaften> kisten) {

        System.out.println("Sie haben " + kisten.size() + " kisten am lager.");
        for (int i = 0; i < kisten.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Kiste NR: " + kisten.get(i).getidNr() + ". Größe ist " + kisten.get(i).getBreite() + " cm breit " + kisten.get(i).getLänge() + " cm lang " + kisten.get(i).getHöhe() + " cm Höhe.");
        }
    }
```

second: Declare kisten as a class property:

```
 ArrayList<KistenEigenschaften> kisten 

public static void main(String[] args) {
   kisten = new ArrayList<KistenEigenschaften>(75);
   ....
   kistenListe();
}

public static void kistenListe() {

        System.out.println("Sie haben " + kisten.size() + " kisten am lager.");
        for (int i = 0; i < kisten.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Kiste NR: " + kisten.get(i).getidNr() + ". Größe ist " + kisten.get(i).getBreite() + " cm breit " + kisten.get(i).getLänge() + " cm lang " + kisten.get(i).getHöhe() + " cm Höhe.");
        }
    }
```

pay Attention to the Java naming convention. class names should start with upper case character.

Do not use german umlauts in property and method names.

`getidNr()` should be `getIdNr()`